# SQL server 2012 management studio fails to start after BSOD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I suffered a blue screen just as I started SQL Management Studio. After the computer restarted when I tried to launch SQL management studio it failed with the message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I did a repair operation thinking that would fix it but to no avail.

The following two event logs are logged in the application log

Log 1:

Source: Application Error

```
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2011.110.3000.0, time stamp: 0x5081c1cd
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18015, time stamp: 0x50b83c8a
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x934
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdfa2a3629ec0a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 7785b9b2-661d-11e2-9af8-083e8e9ddfd9
```

Log 2:

Source: .NET Runtime

```
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException
Stack:
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW(System.Object, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDataSource.GetValue(System.String, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIObject ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.GetValue(System.String, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIObject ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.SetValue(System.String, System.Object)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.MainWindowDataSource.set_IsClosed(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.MainWindow+DataSourceEventSink.Disconnect(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUISimpleDataSource)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.<DisconnectEventSubscribers>b__6(UInt32, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDataSourcePropertyChangeEvents)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.CookieTable`3[[System.UInt32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].ForEach(Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.CookieTableCallback`2<UInt32,System.__Canon>, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.DisconnectEventSubscribers()
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Dispose(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Finalize()
```

What could be wrong? I haven't observed any other issues so I don't know how troubleshoot further.

Comment: I had this one. The registered servers file was corrupted. Use procmon.exe to find out what are the last accessed files before the exception happens. Maybe you can spot the corrupted file.